# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable python 3

Tags: python

I'm completely baffled as to the reason why my code is giving me this error after trying to login into my code. I have a database with a table and I cannot seem to get rid of this annoying error.

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

```
import sqlite3
import sys
import time
import random

conn = sqlite3.connect('tutoral.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def create_table():
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Logins(firstname TEXT, lastname 
TEXT, age REAL, username BLOB, password BLOB, gender TEXT, yeargroup 
REAL)")

# Get login details from user
def login():
    print("<<<<<<<<<Welcome>>>>>>>>>")
    user = input('Username:')
    passw = '%%%s%%' % input('Password:')
    if user == "Charles" and passw =="123123":
        print("Logging in...")
        time.sleep(3)
        print ("ACCESS GRANTED")
        time.sleep(1)
        print('')
        print ("                  <<Welcome Admin>>")
    elif user != "Charles" and passw !="123123":
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM Logins WHERE password=? AND 
username=?'(passw,user))
        if c.fetchall():
            print('Welcome')
        else:
            print('Login failed')
```

Comment: Share the full error message including the line it is on

Comment: in login
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM Logins WHERE password=? AND username=?;'(passw,user))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: `c.execute('SELECT * FROM Logins WHERE password=? AND 
username=?'(passw,user))` is missing a  comma , it should be `c.execute('SELECT * FROM Logins WHERE password=? AND 
username=?', (passw,user))`

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM Logins WHERE password=? AND username=?', (passw,user))
```

You're missing a comma.

Answer (score 0):

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM Logins WHERE password=? AND username=?'(passw,user))
```

Here you missed a comma separating your 2 arguments.

So now the brackets are right next to your string which looks like you're trying to call the string as a function. like..

```
"a string"(arg1, arg2)
```

But like the error message says, Strings are not callable like a function is. So you get that error.

You just need to add a comma in to seperate them and show they are 2 different arguments in your execute function.

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM Logins WHERE password=? AND username=?',(passw,user))
```